# How to kill the default browser process that was opened using webrowser() in python

Tags: python, browser

```
import webbrowser

br=webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com/')
if br==True:
   print"Success"
   print"need to close the browser"
```

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. Are you trying to see if there is an internet connection? Then you could simply use urllib...

Comment: The return value of `webbrowser.open` is not documented. Check for errors via exception `webbrowser.Error`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But you can use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead to open the browser and use the [`terminate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) or [`kill`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) methods.